# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajaxForm is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to submit the form using ajaxForm and redirect to the view. But, I am getting uncaught type error (...).ajaxForm is not a function.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadMainInputs();
    loadSubCategory(<?php echo $model->category_id; ?>);
    $("#Posts-form").ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function () {
            return $("#Posts-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: {
                        max: "Customize Your Error"
                    }
                }
            }).form();
        },
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            $("#btn-save").html("Loading....");
            $("#btn-delete").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            if (result.id != 0) {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("posts"); ?>/";
            }
            showResponse(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you install the Jquery Plugin "ajaxForm"?

Comment: Have you included plugin source file to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajaxForm function appears to not be native from jQuery and instead comes from a jQuery plugin, [jQuery Form Plugin](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/). Including this plugin in your code should solve your problem.